# Why this TensorFlow Transformer model has Linear output instead of Softmax?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism

I am checking this official TensorFlow tutorial on a [Transformer model for Portuguese-English translation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer).

I am quite surprised that [when the Transformer is created](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#create_the_transformer), their final output is a Dense layer with **linear activation**, instead of **Softmax**. Why is that the case? In the original paper [Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) the image is pretty clear, there is a Softmax layer just at the end (Fig.1, p. 3).

How can you justify this difference, when your task involves building a language model and your Loss is based on sparse categorical crossentropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is precisely in the definition of the loss:

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')
```

As you can see, the loss is created with the flag `from_logits=True` which means that the input to the loss is not a probability distribution, but unnormalized log probabilities, namely "logits", which is precisely the result of the final projection, before any softmax.

When `from_logits` is `true`, the softmax itself is handled inside the loss, combining it with the sparse categorical cross-entropy into a more numerically stable form.

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy):

> from_logits:  Whether y_pred is expected to be a logits tensor. By default, we assume that y_pred encodes a probability distribution.
>
> Note - Using from_logits=True may be more numerically stable.

Comment: Ok I'm familiar with `from_logits=True`, I supposed you don't need a Softmax because that Loss is simply taking the token with the highest value attributed, and using that for the prediction. Is a linear output preferable because it brackpropagates error better than softmax?

Comment: No, the softmax is computed, but by the SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object itself (when `from_logits=True`), that's why you don't add it again to the model.